# Padding doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I try to add top-space to my subtitle, but it doesn't work. It's ok, when I put class spacer-top to the class with row - how can I add spacer-top to the mainsubtitle?
**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="about">
     <div class="row">
            <mainsubtitle class="spacer-top">Something</mainsubtitle>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#about{
text-align: center;
background-color: #ffffff;}

mainsubtitle{
padding-top: 50px;
font-family: 'Lato Regular', 'Lato';
font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 36px;
color: #000;
text-align: center;}

.spacer-top {
padding-top: 100px;
padding-bottom: 0px;}
```

Comment: Custom elements such as you have here are likely to have unusual interactions in browsers. Use a proper sematic **current** HTML tag for consistency.

Comment: What is the full context of your code? Is it possible to show a little more HTML?

Comment: Padding works just fine on `<mainsubtitle>` - it just doesn't do what you think it does. But you don't properly describe what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you're making elements like that as custom elements aren't always supported, but this code works fine:

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="about">
     <div class="row">
            <div id="mainsubtitle">Something</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#about{
text-align: center;
background-color: #ffffff;}

#mainsubtitle{
padding-top: 50px;
font-family: 'Lato Regular', 'Lato';
font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 36px;
color: #000;
text-align: center;}
```

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ae5jcxe5/